# How to retrieve the top 3 highest salary and top 3 lowest salary from each dept simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to know if is it possible to display top 3 highest salaried employees from each dept side by side in output with lowest 3 salaried employees of same dept using sql oracle or mysql. I tried using analytical functions and corelated subquery method but could get only the highest or lowest but not both at once. Any insight to this would be appreciaed.

DDL AND DML:

```
CREATE TABLE "EMP" ( "EMPNO"      NUMBER(4,0),"ENAME"      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),"JOB"        VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),"MGR"        NUMBER(4,
 0),"HIREDATE"   DATE,"SAL"        NUMBER(7,2),"COMM"       NUMBER(7,2),"DEPTNO"     NUMBER(2,0),CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP" PRIMARY KEY
 ( "EMPNO" )


Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',null,to_date('17-11-81','DD-MM-RR'),5000,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (8967,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('27-12-19','DD-MM-RR'),3000,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('09-06-81','DD-MM-RR'),2450,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-01-82','DD-MM-RR'),1300,null,10);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('03-12-81','DD-MM-RR'),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (8900,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('27-12-19','DD-MM-RR'),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('19-04-87','DD-MM-RR'),3000,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('02-04-81','DD-MM-RR'),2975,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('23-05-87','DD-MM-RR'),1100,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-80','DD-MM-RR'),800,null,20);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('01-05-81','DD-MM-RR'),2850,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-02-81','DD-MM-RR'),1600,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('08-09-81','DD-MM-RR'),1500,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-09-81','DD-MM-RR'),1250,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-02-81','DD-MM-RR'),1250,null,30);
Insert into EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) values (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('03-12-81','DD-MM-RR'),950,null,30);
```

Comment: Pick a database and run with it. Otherwise, if someone answers for Oracle, and someone else answers for MySQL, which one do you 'accept'?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this one:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT e.*, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY sal DESC) AS sal_desc,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY sal ASC) AS sal_ASC
    FROM EMP e)
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE sal_desc <= 3 OR sal_ASC <= 3
```